# Nilpotent elements in the quotient ring of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $F$ is a field and $p(x) \in F[x]$, prove that the ring $R=F[x]/(p(x))$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements iff $p(x)$ is not divisible by the square of any polynomial.

(==>)

$R$ has no nonzero nilpotent element, but $p(x)$ is divisible by the square of some $g(x)\in F[x], \deg g(x)>0$
Say $p(x)=(g(x))^2h(x)$ for some $h(x)\in F[x]$, then consider $g(x)h(x)\in F[x]$, $0<\deg g(x)h(x)=\deg g(x)+\deg h(x)\le \deg p(x)$, but $(g(x)h(x))^2=g^2(x)h^2(x)=p(x)h(x)=\bar{0}$ in $F[x]/(p(x))$, it is a contradition.

(<==)
$p(x)$ is not divisible by the square of any polynomial, and there is nonzero nilpotent element, say $f(x), (f(x))^n=0$, for some n.
Then, $p(x)|(f(x))^n$ but $p(x)\nmid f(x)$.

Then I don't know how to continue...

Also, is there any way to proof directly?

Comment: Two hints: 1) Can you do this with quotient rings of $\Bbb{Z}$? Can you prove that there are nilpotent elements in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_m$ if and only if $m$ is divisible by a non-trivial square? If you can, then mimick that proof! 2) The prime numbers in $\Bbb{Z}$ share many key properties with irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$. Such as... (the latter hint can be rephrased using common properties of the respective rings).

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}$, we have $p\nmid a$ but $p|a^n$. Wow, is it, I reduce a into production of some primes, $p|a^n$ means that $p$ can choose some of the $primes^n$, for some $n$. If any of $n$ is less than $1$, $n|a$, so there must be at least a prime with square $n>1$, say $b^n$, $b^n|p$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x)+I$ is a nonzero nilpotent element in $F[x]/I$, where $I=(p(x))$. Then, for some $n>1$, $f(x)^n\in I$, that is, $p(x)$ divides $f(x)^n$.

It is not restrictive to assume $p(x)$ is monic.

Let $p(x)=p_1(x)^{m_1}p_2(x)^{m_2}\dots p_k(x)^{m_k}$ be the decomposition of $p$ into (monic) prime powers.

Since $p(x)$ does not divide $f(x)$, there is $j$ such that $p_j(x)^{m_j}$ doesn't divide $f(x)$. However, this polynomial divides $f(x)^n$, hence $p_j(x)$ divides $f(x)$. Therefore $m_j>1$.

Conversely, suppose $q(x)^2$ divides $p(x)$, with non constant $q(x)$. Consider $f(x)=p(x)/q(x)^2$. Then $p(x)=q(x)^2f(x)$, so $p(x)$ divides $(q(x)f(x))^2$ and therefore $q(x)f(x)$ is nilpotent. Let's see it is nonzero in $F[x]/I$, that is, that $p(x)$ doesn't divide $q(x)f(x)$: indeed
$$
q(x)f(x)=p(x)g(x)=f(x)q(x)^2g(x)
$$
implies
$$
q(x)g(x)=1
$$
and $q(x)$ would be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Take $p$ a monic non-null polynomial and write its (unique) decomposition as a product of monic irreducible polynomials :

$$p=q_1^{\alpha_1}...q_r^{\alpha_r} $$

Then by the Chinese Remainder theorem :

$$F[x]/(p)\text{ is isomorphic to } F[x]/(q_1^{\alpha_1})\times...\times  F[x]/(q_r^{\alpha_r})$$

Now suppose $\alpha_1=...=\alpha_r=1$ (i.e. $p$ is squarefree) then

$$F[x]/(p)\text{ is isomorphic to } F[x]/(q_1)\times...\times  F[x]/(q_r)$$

Cannot have non-zero nilpotent elements because it is a product ring of fields : assume $(a_1,...,a_r)^n=0$ in $F[x]/(q_1)\times...\times  F[x]/(q_r)$ then $a_i^n=0$ for each $i$ but you are in a field so $a_i=0$.

On the other hand suppose $\alpha_1\geq 2$ then :

$$(q_1,0,...,0)\neq 0 \text{ in } F[x]/(q_1^{\alpha_1})\times...\times  F[x]/(q_r^{\alpha_r}) $$

But clearly :

$$(q_1,0,...,0)^{\alpha_1}=(q_1^{\alpha_1},0,...,0)=(0,...,0)\text{ in }F[x]/(q_1^{\alpha_1})\times...\times  F[x]/(q_r^{\alpha_r}) $$

So it has a nilpotent element. For a direct proof you can show that the nilpotent elements of a product of rings is the product of the set of nilpotent elements of each ring.