# Nilpotent elements in $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^4+4\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ denote the ring of polynomials in $X$ with real coefficients. Then, the quotient ring $R=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4+4)$ is

(a) field

(b) an integral domain, but not a field

(c) not an integral domain, but has $0$ as the only nilpotent element

(d) a ring which contains non-zero nilpotent elements

My approach Since $x^4+4$ can be reducible into two irreduciable polynoimials over $\mathbb{R}$ as $(x^2+2x+2)$ and $(x^2-2x+2)$ and using Chinese Remainder theroem for ideals we can

$$R=\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^4+4)}=\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2+2x+2)} \times \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2-2x+2)}$$

$$=\mathbb{F_1}\times\mathbb{F_2} \tag{1}$$

From $(1)$, we can say that it is not an integral domain as it has zero divisors so it can't be a field So first two options are Wrong.

**Doubt 1** How to find that some nonzero element is nilpotent or not?

Maybe this is bit silly question but I'm curious to know,

**Doubt 2** Is there any difference between two rings that are not integral domains like say $(\mathbb Z_4, +_4, ._4)$ and  $(\mathbb Z_6, +_6, ._6)$ having no. of nilpotent elements are $2$ and $1$ respectively.

Thanks in advanced!

**Edit** Since neither $(x^2+2x+2)$ nor $(x^2-2x+2)$ can't be writen as square or any polynomial in $\mathbb{R[x]}$ (Both polynomials are degree $2$ and have complex root so irreduciable.) [Nilpotent elements in the quotient ring of a polynomial ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234230/nilpotent-elements-in-the-quotient-ring-of-a-polynomial-ring)

So $R$ has only $0$ as the nilpotent element.
and correct option is (c).

Comment: For nilpotent elements see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234230/nilpotent-elements-in-the-quotient-ring-of-a-polynomial-ring), for example.

Comment: $(a,b) \in A\times B$ is nilpotent iff each $a\in A, b\in B$ are nilpotent. Here $A,B$ are fields, only $0$ is nilpotent.

Comment: @reuns thanks for the comment, Sir can we say $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ andclearly $(0,0)$ is nilpotent element.

Answer (score 1):

Given factor ring $$R=\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^4+4)}$$

$(x^4+4)$ is reducible into irreducible polynomials $(x^2+2x+2)$ and $(x^2-2x+2)$ in $\mathbb{R[x]}$ and using Chinese Remainder theroem,

$$R=\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^4+4)}=\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2+2x+2)} \times \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2-2x+2)}$$

$$ R  \approx \mathbb{R[\iota]}\times \mathbb{R[\iota]}$$
$$ R \approx \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$$
Clearly, $(0,0)$ is the only nilpotent element in $R$.